# Edit NAME Opportunities at SugarCRM

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I want to edit the name inside opportunity module of SugarCRM, but not from the fron-end, but using custom code of PHP and SQL. This will enable user to edit the subpanels of the Opportunities module with PHP and SQL.

I can't find the file where I edit the query, for example that instead show the names upwards that show them descending.

I need to know the file location and function to modify it accordingly. Please help.

The image can be seen in this link [IMAGE OPPORTUNITIES SUGARCRM](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/101449/editar-name-opportunities-en-sugarcrm)

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. this community is specifically for asking programming questions. your question relates to configuration of infrastructure, so you'll likely get a better set of answers at serverfault.com

Comment: No my friend, is not configuration.... is programming  in sugarcrm using php and sql query.

Comment: You want to update your fields using PHP and MySQL right?

Comment: @RaviRanjan yes, is true...But I cannot modify the behavior of the SQL query of SugarCRM ooportunities !!

Comment: You can modify let me check using module loader then I will give the code to you.

Comment: you need to learn Sugar a bit more :)

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a logic hooks for this, ie .. after the user clicks save in the registry, you use a logic that replaces the information of the field in question

You could read about this here:
http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Module_Framework/Logic_Hooks/